# How does hardwood floor acclimate to a location with variable humidity?

Tags: hardwood-floor, humidity

I've read in many places that hardwood flooring should be acclimated to the place it will be installed (e.g. [Armstrong flooring](http://www.armstrong.com/flooring/top-10-hardwood.html)).

The local humidity here (Northeast US) regularly varies by 50-70% over the course of a few days (from 40-90%).  The hardwood will be purchased from a box store, where temperature (and therefore humidity by way of A/C) are regulated.

**Given the wide range of humidity conditions at home (where temp/humidity are not regulated) and the fact that the wood is currently in a temp/humidity controlled building, what purpose will acclimation serve?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The humidity swing you mention is accurate for the air, not so for the wood. It does not change that fast. It's all about the MC (moisture content) of the wood when it comes to acclimation. The humidity does affect it but over a period of time.

The main thing about acclimating, is getting the new flooring close enough to the humidity of the location it is going in. Most wood as it comes from the mill is supposed to be around 6% MC. This also depends on the time of year and your location, also, how long the flooring has been in storage and where it is stored at. It is not wise to get flooring that may have had its MC grow to 8% in a warehouse, and immediately laid in a home that is heated in the wintertime and the MC of the wood in the home is at 4%. The wood floor will shrink more than you might want it to. Other factors temper the situation too. As in, whether the floor is flat sliced, quarter or rift sawll this affects how the wood moves after it is laid. The other end of the scale to reverse the situation, you will not want to lay a floor that has just come from the mill at 6% MC and lay it in a house that has not had AC on yet in the summertime and the MC of the wood is at 10% or more, I have had that happen too.

That's the long version of the story why the floor should acclimate before it is laid. The usual length of time has been 2 weeks for acclimation. This way all the wood in the home will gain and loose MC together.

Answer (score 3):

Humidity is variable everywhere. I live in the desert where the indoor humidity varies from 10% to 60% depending on the time of year. I've installed engineered hardwood and it's totally fine. Don't most houses in the northeast have hardwood flooring? I think you'll be totally fine too. Just keep in mind seasonal cycles; if you install during a high-humidity period, expect it to shrink a bit. If you install in a low-humidity period, expect is to expand a bit.

That said, hardwood flooring isn't a the best choice for a building that's not temperature controlled at all, as you've implied.